# how do I load a page with items invisible until jquery .fadeToggle() is triggered?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $(".hint").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I want all elements with the .hint class initially invisible until the button is clicked.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your css, just place a `display: none` where you define your class *hint*. `fadeToggle` will overwrite this with custom styles, directly attached to the element.

Comment: Thanks to all! Learned several different approaches!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.hint
{
display:none;
}
```

Or if you want to hide this with jQuery onload, then add the following:

```
$(".hint").hide();
```

This would go straight after `$(document).ready()` like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hint").hide();
$("button").click(function(){ ....
```

Comment: Your second option won't work, as it would be *onload*, which is not what he asked for (to be initially invisible)

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is ran at load though so this would then hide it?

Comment: *onload* or *ready* will be triggered when the document is ready, i.e. all css is parsed. It would be visible for a moment. Probably to short to get the difference ..! EDIT: I've reread the jquery doc. It is after DOM construction (which *would* lead to a short moment of visibility).

Answer (score 0):

Define a css

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And add it to your html element,

```
   <.... class="hint hidden" ...>
```

Or just add `display: none` to `.hint` css definition unless you are using `.hint` in other places where you it to be visible.

This way the element is hidden on load.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code to cause them to hide, so you must have them hidden in css..change css

Answer (score 0):

a good way to do this is to define a css class .hidden

then you can `addClass` or `removeClass` the class with jQuery, you can even `toggleClass`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
        $(".hint").toggleClass("hidden");
        // if you want to preserve the fadeToggle just add display:none to the .hint css class
        });
    });
 </script>
```

css:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
 }
```

in your HTML you have to add the hidden class to the .hint elements so that they are hidden initially.

```
<div class="hint hidden"></div>
```